# Visual Studio linked files with different name

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm sharing a file between projects. The original file has been added into a Xamarin Android project as an Asset inside the Assets folder.

The original file is named "Container.xaml", but due to **naming restrictions in Android**, the name should be lowercase. Is it possible to make the link file be in lowercase while keeping the original untouched?

Comment: If possible, I suggest rename the file name and put it into the  Android Asset folder.

Comment: But that implies that the file isn't shared anymore, so I would have to manually sync copies

Comment: Have you solved this problem? What about  to rename the original file to lowercase?

Comment: Maybe you can use before build step to copy and rename the file.